# grep lines starting with - or plus from yum command output

Tags: grep

I am running a yum query

```
 yum group info 'X Window System'
```

where the output is as follows

```
yum group info 'X Window System'
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.vanehost.com
* extras: mirror.vanehost.com
* updates: mirror.vanehost.com

 Group: X Window System
 Group-Id: x11
 Description: X Window System Support.
 Mandatory Packages:
 -glx-utils
 -initial-setup-gui
 =mesa-dri-drivers
 =plymouth-system-theme
 =spice-vdagent
 +xorg-x11-drivers
 =xorg-x11-server-Xorg
 =xorg-x11-utils
 =xorg-x11-xauth
 =xorg-x11-xinit
 =xvattr
 Optional Packages:
mesa-libGLES
 tigervnc-server
 wayland-protocols-devel
 xorg-x11-drv-evdev
 xorg-x11-drv-keyboard
 xorg-x11-drv-libinput
 xorg-x11-drv-mouse
 xorg-x11-drv-openchrome
```

But when ever i am running a grep on this to filter out lines starting with - or +

```
yum group info 'X Window System' | grep -E "^[-+]"
```

I am getting a blank output. Can some one pls let me know where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines don't start with `+` or `-`, they start with whitespace. Try

```
grep -E "^[[:blank:]]*[-+]"
```